# Sequelize: where with include based on parent's column

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have two Models, A and B.

```
A.hasMany(B, {
      foreignKey: "A.id",
      as: "A.id",
    });

B.belongsTo(A, {
      foreignKey: "B.id",
      as: "B.id",
});
```

I want all the data from table A and all the associated data(from table B), except when `A.isActive = false`(in which case I need only from table A). I'm not able to find any way to do it with sequelize. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  A.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: B
            }
        ],
        where: { isActive: true }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this would give me the entries when A.isActive = false.

Comment: it gives you all records from A including model B ,except when isActive=false

Comment: Yes, but I need all the data from A in either case and the association only when A.isActive = true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try LEFT JOIN with condition.

```js
A.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: B,
        required: false,
        where: { 
            '$A.isActive$': true
        } 
    }]
})
```

Comment: I tried this method, apparently I had to remove 2 options from the include, i.e. {separate: true, limit: 1} for it to work. If I try without removing these options, I get "Unknown column: 'A.isActive'" error. Can we have a way by which I can include these options(atleast {limit: 1}) and do the LEFT JOIN as well?

Comment: could you try `subQuery: false` on the parent (same level as the first `include`)?  and do not use `separate: true`

Comment: It doesn't work unless I remove {limit: 1}

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10165
Maybe this is an issue with sequelize?

Comment: After so many years yet this issue is still not fixed